# “error ld returned 1 exit status” when i use "boost::log::add_file_log()" function

Tags: c++, boost

The code：

```
#include <boost/log/support/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/text_file_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>


int main()
{
    boost::log::add_file_log(
       boost::log::keywords::auto_flush = true,
       boost::log::keywords::file_name = "log%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.%N.log",
       boost::log::keywords::rotation_size = 10 * 1024 * 1024,

       /*if delete here, the compiler was successful*/
       boost::log::keywords::format  = "[%TimeStamp%] (%Severity%) : %Message%",
       boost::log::keywords::min_free_space=3 * 1024 * 1024
       );
}
```

I try compile this code,but prompt information：“error ld returned 1 exit status”.

if I delete `boost::log::keywords::format  = "[%TimeStamp%] (%Severity%) : %Message%",` this code can be compiled successfully.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, you probably need to link `boost::log` http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/arXefqk76MJoV7SC

Answer (score 3):

You need to build and link the Boost log library for this code to work, see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/installation/config.html.

Comment: thanks,but i also link -lboost_system, -lboost_thread, -lboost_log, -lpthread, and define BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK

Comment: @object yes, that's the `link` part of my answer

Answer (score 0):

When I add `-lboost_log_setup` and rebuild the project, this problem is resolved.

So，it should be link `-lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_log -lpthread -lboost_log_setup`